# How to post data and read a database in every 5seconds once

Tags: java, android, database

I am a beginner in the android studio. I will successfully connect the database but I don't know how to read a data 5 seconds once in an android studio.
I want to how to read data from the database every 5 seconds once

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... voids) {

    String result = "";
    String name = voids[0];
    String word = voids[1];
    Log.d("myTag", "This is my test");
    String connstr ="http://192.168.43.123/suruthi/login.php";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(connstr);
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        http.setRequestMethod("POST");
        http.setDoInput(true);
        http.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream ops = http.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(ops, "UTF-8"));
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8")
                +"&&"+ URLEncoder.encode("pass", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(word, "UTF-8");
        writer.write(data);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        ops.close();
        InputStream ips = http.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips, "ISO-8859-1"));
        String line ="";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            result += line;
        }

        reader.close();
        ips.close();
        http.disconnect();
        return result;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        result = e.getMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        result = e.getMessage();
    }
    return result;
    }

    }
```

The below timer function is working only image changes but it is not suitable for reading a database ever 5 sec once

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!isInterrupted()) {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                       /* iv.setImageResource(mThumbIds[i]);
                        i++;
                        if(i >= mThumbIds.length)
                        {
                        i=0;
                        }*/
                        doInBackground();
                    }
                });}}
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
        }}};
        }
```

I tried above the timer function to read a database but it is not working..please guide me to resolve the issues..

Comment: Please tell me your problem in detail.I am not seen any timer in your program.Do you have any timer Part?

Comment: Please post the timer detail

Comment: So you want to changing an ImageView src depending on database field data change

Comment: yes i want to change the image by database value but the problem is i am unable to fetch the value from the database after the first time. I am used timer for continuous operation but it is work only the first time after that it shows unfortunately stopped